# JPA repository works in IDEA and production, but not in gradle

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, gradle, spring-data

I'm using a Spring data JPA repository.

My tests are working well in IDEA and production code is working in Tomcat, but while runnung gradle tests I receive exception that application context can't be created

```
... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.test.FullNamespaceConfig
```

My class has @Entity annotation and inherits from another class with @MappedSuperclass

What may be wrong here? What is the difference in running in IDEA and in gradle (IDEA project was generated using gradle idea)

It is gradle module with spring:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.reports"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>

</bean>

<!-- Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory-->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernatePersistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="${database.showSql}"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test"/>
</bean>

<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.test.dao"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle puts classes and resources in separate output directories, which JPA doesn't like. Try:

```
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
```

Comment: how do you do the equivalent in 2019 where (quote) "File classesDir has been replaced by FileCollection classesDirs"? 

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-get-unknown-property-classesdir-for-main-classes-of-type-org-gradle-api-internal-tasks-defaultsourcesetoutput/30570

Answer (score 0):

Limited info but it seems like com.test.FullNamespaceConfig is an entity, correct ? And it resides in your test project ? If so then maybe your missing a persistence.xml file in the test project which means that the entity is not detected. 
it would be helpful if you could provide some more data about the project structure.

Comment: Added spring xml to the question